# Stringbuilder append newline in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am still learning Spring Roo so please bear with me.  Here is what I have (generated by roo)

```
public String convert(Cluster cluster) {
        return new StringBuilder().append(cluster.getName()).toString();
    }
```

so what that produces is this.

```
<div id="_s_com_clusters_id" class="box">Cluster1,Cluster2,Cluster3,Cluster4,Cluster5,Cluster6</div>
```

Which displayed

Cluster1,Cluster2,Cluster3,Cluster4,Cluster5,Cluster6

to the webpage.

What I want to do is insert a new line instead of the "," i tried append("\n") and that added a space between each but that was it.

Edit:
I have also tried append("
") as well and the generated html is

```
<div id="_s_com_clusters_id" class="box">Cluster1&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster2&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster3&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster4&‌​lt;br/&gt;,Cluster5&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster6&lt;br/&gt;</div>
```

Which results in

Cluster1<br/>,Cluster2<br/>,Cluster3<br/>,Cluster4&‌​lt;br/>,Cluster5<br/>,Cluster6<br/>

being displayed on the webpage.

Comment: Should be `<br/>` instead of \n, but I don't know anything about Roo to answer if it will escape that HTML.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that your spring configuration escapes HTML code. Check if there is something like that :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in your web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should be fine:

```
append("<br/>");
```

Comment: by adding that then between the div tags it shows `<div id="_s_com_clusters_id" class="box">Cluster1&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster2&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster3&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster4&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster5&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster6&lt;br/&gt;</div>`

Comment: Yea I actually didn't notice the missing / what I put in was append("<br/>") and the result was my previous comment.

Comment: No unfortunately it's not. the html it generates is `<div id="_s_com_clusters_id" class="box">Cluster1&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster2&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster3&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster4&‌​lt;br/&gt;,Cluster5&lt;br/&gt;,Cluster6&lt;br/&gt;</div>` and the result that is displayed on the page is Cluster1<br/>,Cluster2<br/>,...

Comment: do you have a demo page running somewhere where I can see the output

Comment: No it is just running on my machine.  I edited my initial question to hopefully illustrate the problem a little bit more.