# How do I output HTML to be rendered in Spring-Roo MVC list.jspx view?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-roo

I'd like to display a list of links using Spring Roo.  I have a model class and its corresponding list view, with which I'd like to display the text description field linked with its URL.

The problem is that Spring Roo escapes my text and prints out

Here's the model class

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class RooListItem {
    private String description;
    private String uri;

    @ManyToOne
    private RooList rooList;

    public String getHtmlView() {
        return "<a href=\""+uri+"\">"+description+"</a>";
    }
}
```

And the corresponding snippet in the list.jspx view

```
<table:table data="${roolistitems}" id="l_my_package_model_RooListItem" path="/roolistitems" z="nDXBSp5nQX1Z210Pn2j84U/3Yz0=">
    <table:column id="c_my_package_model_RooListItem_htmlView" property="htmlView" z="user-managed"/>
    <table:column id="c_my_package_model_RooListItem_rooList" property="rooList" z="KzSXHmY6K+B7FkMvafSA5JiwKW0="/>

</table:table>
```

I'm using Spring Roo 1.2.1 with Jetty.  Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220340/stringbuilder-append-newline-in-spring-mvc).  Thanks, pith!  Setting the defaultHtmlEscape parameter to true allows me to display HTML.  Is there a solution that will allow HTML to appear in more limited portions of the Roo project?  (As opposed to changing a global setting?)

Comment: I should read my example more carefully.  The defaultHtmlEscape parameter allowed me to put HTML in field:display tags, but not table:column.